# Removing repeating rows from dataframe based on multiple columns in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

If i have a table of events:

| timestamp | unit | state 1 | state n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01:00 | a | x | n_1 |
| 02:00 | a | x | n_2 |
| 03:00 | a | y | n_3 |
| 04:00 | a | x | n_4 |
| 05:00 | b | x | n_5 |

Lets say we want to keep the first occurrence of events by unit only based on state 1.
For this this means that the observation at 02:00 irrelevant and we want to remove it.

Removing duplicates is common but if we try to get distinct values of state 1 we also remove the event at 04:00 and get this table.

| timestamp | unit | state 1 | state n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01:00 | a | x | n_1 |
| 03:00 | a | y | n_3 |
| 05:00 | b | x | n_5 |

We still want to keep the value at 04:00 to not lose info on the state change, so in essence we do not want to remove duplicates and we want to remove repeating rows.

In addition we would also want consider the situation with `n>=2` states.

How do i remove/filter out the rows containing repeating data based on several columns.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this is to add a column of all the states as a struct and use lag/lead to check if the earlier struct is identical.

```
windowPart = partitionBy('unit').orderBy(col('timestamp'))

df = (
spark.read.table("events")
    .select(
    "*",
    struct('state 1', 'state 2', 'state 1-n', 'state n').alias('states')
    .withColumn(
    'repeating',
    lead('states').over('windowPart') == col('states')
    )
    .filter(col('repeating') == True)
    .drop('states')
)
```

This works, but creating a separate column struct for this and then dropping it feels unnecessary.

Is there a better way to do this or should i just let the optimization of the execution plan do its work and be satisfied with this solution?